# Merging MySQL Structure and Data

Tags: mysql, merge

I have a MySQL database running on a deployment machine which also contains data. Then I have another MySQL database which has evolved in terms of STRUCTURE + DATA for some time. I need a way to merge the changes (ONLY) for both structure and data to the DB in deployment machine without disturbing the existing data. Does anyone know of a tool available which can do this safely. I have had a look at a few comparison tools but I need a tool which can automate the merge operation. Note also that most of the data in the tables is in BINARY so I can't use many file comparison tools. Does any one know of a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

I doubt you can get around implementing your own diff & merge without paying a lot.

Read the structures on both databases, execute a few alter table [table] add column [foo] statements to update the structure, then port data line by line (SELECT * on old Database, UPDATE [new columns] WHERE [primary key conditions]).

There is no easier way to my knowledge.

Comment: @dbemerlin: I thought of this but I have over 200 tables and this can get tedious :)